# Self link modules in terraform

Tags: module, terraform

I have the following terraform code snippet where I'm trying to use a self_link in the subnet.network resource that references the title of the network resource.

main.tf

```
resource "google_compute_network" "demo-vpc-network" {
  auto_create_subnetworks         = "false"
  delete_default_routes_on_create = "false"
  name                            = var.GCP_COMPUTE_NETWORK_NAME
  project                         = var.GCP_PROJECT_NAME
  routing_mode                    = "REGIONAL"
}
 
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "demo-subnet" {
  ip_cidr_range            = "10.200.0.0/24"
  name                     = "kubernetes"
  network                  = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self.link
  private_ip_google_access = "false"
  project                  = var.GCP_PROJECT_NAME
  region                   = "us-west1"
}
```

However, I get the following error.

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on main.tf line 77, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "demo-subnet":
  77:   network                  = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self.link

A managed resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" has not been
declared in the root module.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
google_compute_network.vpc_network.self.link
```

won't work because **google_compute_network.vpc_network** doesn't exist.

It's easy to fix because **google_compute_network.demo-vpc-network** does exist.

Update: Also, as you've noted in your comment **self-link** (with a hyphen) won't work and needs to be [**self_link** (with an underscore)](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_network.html#self_link).

Here's the second resource block with the bug fixed:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "demo-subnet" {
  ip_cidr_range            = "10.200.0.0/24"
  name                     = "kubernetes"
  network                  = google_compute_network.demo-vpc-network.self.link
  private_ip_google_access = "false"
  project                  = var.GCP_PROJECT_NAME
  region                   = "us-west1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. There was a minor adjustment needed in the self link. Should be an underscore, not a period.

google_compute_network.demo-vpc-network.self_link

Comment: @gofmf thank you for noting that! I've corrected that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the resource for the main network is:

> resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network"

Then you could set a name for it with the property:

> name = demo-vpc-network

Check [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_network.html) for more details